# quick leave and enter cause multiple element in angular ng-if animation

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angular-ng-if

there is a ng-if animation example in this doc:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf
if you clicking the checkbox quickly and repeatedly,you will find more than one element will be displayed,I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: in the class .animate-if you can give position:absolute;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because `ngIf` behaves different to `ngShow` for example. `ngShow` simply adds a `display: none` style to the element that must be hidden, while ngIf does the following:

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

So if the animation takes a bit long, there will be more than one element in the DOM.

In Olivvv's example, if you just change the delay of `.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave` to `0.001s` you will se that you cannot get more than one element.

Here for you to see it is a forked version of the official AngularJS documentation. http://plnkr.co/edit/ok7nwOIRpR1TYYRkBRXj?p=preview

I have only modified its delay from `0.5s` to `0.001s`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the cloning is faster than the removing, and they don't block each-other ? so if want to keep the animation "long", what is the solution ? add a debouncer to prevent clicks to trigger toggle action whilst the animation is still running ? (btw, shouldn't angular as a framework take care of this? imo we should not get race conditions just by using the most standard condition)

Comment: First of all remember AngularJS is being used by millions of people, so I believe that for the dilemma of keeping it standard but forcing you to use it that way, or giving you freedom to use it as you want, they kept with the second.

Comment: So another thing you should consider, is using ngShow, which is considered a better solution when the state is being modified often. You don't need to remove it from de DOM and recreate it each time. You could do what you mentioned with a debouncer to prevent clicks but, is that a good UX solution? Or it is just an almost-dirty workaround?

Comment: I will suggest to use ngShow if the state can be modified by the user, because the user could simply keep changing the state quite often. I belive ngIf was not thought for things like this.

Comment: @Olivvv could you assign the bounty?

Comment: no sorry it seems that I cant, I am not the author of the original question.

Comment: Thank you very much, glad to help you!